# Sudo access Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on PI4

Tags: sudo

I am the only sudo user, i no longer have sudo access and pi install does not use grub. how do i recover and get me back as a sudo user
[image: Terminal]

Comment: If it was me, I'd modify your sd-card (or hdd/ssd partition) `/etc/sudoers` file on another box. My own *pi* has its config on SD card, thus its fast to eject, then insert into usb module & I'd make change on a desktop system (*assuming you didn't plan for mistake by adding another user, or enable root account*)

Comment: Add your name to the `sudo` line in the `/etc/group` file on the sd-card.

Comment: "*no longer have sudo access*" suggests that either you system simply forgot about you (very unlikely), or that you manually caused the problem (possible but rare), or that something else has gone terribly wrong that may require a complete reinstall...and you just don't know about it yet.

Comment: fyi:  I mentioned `/etc/sudoers` in my first comment due to *assumption* on my behalf (*ps: I know, assumption is the mother of all stuff-ups*).. any error in the sudoers file is treated as EOF or *end of file* meaning subsequent lines are ignored.. thus I read your not having `sudo` access as you making a mistake in that file..  Where your error is I do not know; my assumption maybe incorrect.. thus file you should change may differ to what I suggested in first comment